# How to implement postsharp attributes as Interfaces

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, postsharp, aop

I have a simple exception handling attribute. The problem is we use that attribute in the common project and it creates a dependency to all of our projects. How can we remove the Postsharp dependency from the common project and inject the Postsharp using Autofac.

- Our goal is to update the Nuget packages easily from the root project

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is not possible to apply aspects using Autofac.

If you apply aspects using attributes then you need reference PostSharp.dll because it defines base classes of your aspect.

But you can [add aspects](http://doc.postsharp.net/xml-multicasting) using a project level [xml configuration](http://doc.postsharp.net/configuration-system) file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.postsharp.org/1.0/configuration"
         xmlns:m="clr-namespace:MyAspectLibrary;assembly:MyAspectLibrary">
  <Multicast>
    <m:MyAspect AttributeTargetTypes="MyProject.Class1" AttributeTargetMembers="Method1" />
  </Multicast>
</Project>
```

The file must have the same name and must be placed in the same folder as csproj file with psproj extension (here `MyProject.psproj`).

In this case you can remove reference to PostSharp.dll from `MyProject`. It needs to be still referenced from `MyAspectLibrary`.

Edit: Note that `MyProject` has to be still post-processed by PostSharp. See PostSharp.targets and related lines in csproj file.

Comment: Most likely it is not possible to apply aspects using Autofac.
 :((